# QlikView - Bar Borders

Tags: qlikview

I have a grouped bar chart in QlikView - the bars are displayed in different colors. Is it possible display the last bar in a group so that the border of the bar is red, and the middel of the bar is white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; you can't do what you want to do.

You can individually set the thickness/presence of the bars but you can not change the colours of those borders. You will also need to set-up an expression for each you can not affect the border thickness based on the dimensions

[image]

[image]

And you can colour the bars as per the dimension quite effectively, so without bothering about the borders you can make the last bar always red, you just need to know the dimension you are working with

So this:
[image]

Will give you this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, within the bar chart object bars do not have a border.